# Concurrent Remote Desktop Connection on VM in Server 2012

Tags: virtual-machine, rdp, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to Server and VM things. I recently have the following  scenario:

I have 1 physical server that has server 2012 R2 installed on it. 
My task is to setup two windows 7 VM environment by hyper-v for testing.

Since there are more than two people accessing the VMs in the future. I know the existing user is kicked when another user login to the VM. Is there any ways to configure this such that both users can access without being kicked? (without violating the terms)

I heard about remote desktop service and did some research on it. However, I do not know if it would fit on this scenario. If it fits, can you explain how it will work?

If none of that work, I am thinking my last plan will be setting up more VMs for the group to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first add Hyper-v role in your server from server manager.

Since you are planning to add two virtual machines, you must assign 2 static IPs to each of the VMs.

To run concurrent two RDPs in windows 7, you can install [this patch](https://forum.sambapos.com/t/step-by-step-on-how-to-configure-multiple-concurrent-rdp-clients-to-run-sambapos-iphone-ipad-galaxy-tablet/769) in your VM that has windows 7 OS. Once you have added the patch restart the VM and you will be able to access VM with 2 different user concurrently.